# jasperreports и термопринтер

Tags: java, принтер, jasperreports

За основу взял [этот пример](http://www.mets-blog.com/java-pos-thermal-printer-example/)

и решил шаблон сделать с помощью jasperreports и отдельно создал класс который работает уже с шаблоном...

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("qwe");
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);

    InputStream reportPath =
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Bill.jasper");
    JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(), beanCollectionDataSource);
    byte[] output = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    return output;
```

а вот когда запустил притер напечатал метровую портянку... )))) при этом ниче понятного не распечаталась...

хотя когда пользуюсь `JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);` то получаю то что надо вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже проблема с размерами страницы. Попробуйте сделать экспорт в пдф файл и проверить параметры страницы, правильно ли указан размер страницы, при просмотре, например, adobe reader? если да, то проблема в инициализации принтера в джаспере, возможно там где-то стоит указать параметры страницы

Comment: @DaysLikeThis размеры норм из полученного ПДФ печатал на этом же принтере все норм

Comment: Я никогда через джаспер не печатал, но если пдфка нормальная, попробуйте распечатать через PDFBox (от апача который), он прост в использовании. В любом случае, если разберетесь в чем проблема, пожалуйста, ответьте на свой вопрос, мне тоже интересно знать, в чем была проблема :)

Comment: @DaysLikeThis ОК, без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

@DaysLikeThis как обещал кидаю листинг, может ещё кому то пригодитсяи кому пригодится:

```
try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("qwe");
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds= new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);

        InputStream reportPath =
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Bill1.jasper");

        System.out.println(reportPath);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap<>(), ds);

        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        PageFormat pageFormat = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
        printerJob.defaultPage(pageFormat);

        int selectedService = 0;

        AttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet(new PrinterName("XP-80C", null));

        PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, attributeSet);

        try {
            printerJob.setPrintService(printService[selectedService]);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        // these are deprecated
        exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, printService[selectedService]);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printService[selectedService].getAttributes());
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();

    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

некоторые методы деприкейтед, ещё не успел исправить... если у кого нибудь будет возможность это сделать то был бы благодарен ;) спасибо за советы!